# MongoDB index changing when assigned to express-session variable

Tags: mongodb, express, express-session

I have this section of code executing after a mongoDB return:

```
              //SUCCESS
              req.session.name = instructor[0].name;
              req.session.id = instructor[0]._id;

...

              console.log(instructor[0]._id);
              console.log(req.session.id);
```

Which returns.

```
58d311bd03b090b704000009
0pjG3EBuRsQPARWKhyRH67cv71wzkJPp
```

How Do I prevent the id from changing when I assign it to its session variable?

Comment: you are printing  '_id' value but assigning 'id' value .. or is this just typo while typing it up here?

Comment: It was a typo, it has been corrected

Answer (score 0):

In express-session, it turns out req.session.id / ._id contain the sessions id itself.

I fixed this by changing:

```
req.session.id = instructor[0]._id;
```

to

```
req.session.userid = instructor[0].id;
```